# Incorrect argc value when executing with "*"

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
        printf("\n argc : %d \n",argc);
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[root@aman]# ./a.out *

argc : 8
```

I have passed two arguments, so the argc value has to be 2, but it is showing as 8. 
I wanted to store the * in a array and compare the inputted '*' string.

I was writing a tool to remove all the entries in the list. Hence I need to verify the * from the "./a.out *" whether its inputted .
If inputted I need to do actions corresponding to it.Is there a way to use as ./a.out * and take the * the user has inputted.

Comment: It expands the list of file names by the shell.

Comment: Actually, the `argc` would typically be the number of arguments you've passed plus 1 (so should be 3 in this case).

Answer (score 6):

Your shell is expanding `*` to a list of files in the current folder. Try quoting the `*` by enclosing it in double or single quotes.

You could have found out yourself by iterating over `argv` and printing all the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

On a UNIX like operating system the system shell expands operators like "*" before executing the command. The * operator will list all files in the current directory and supply it as a list of parameters to your program. It is very likely that you have exactly 8 files in your working directory. Try to put the star in "*" if you really want to provide a * as input parameter to your program.

Answer (score 1):

When you are running the binary, the input `argv[]` is considered as the number of the files present in that directory.

The `*` in a shell environment usually denotes all files present in that directory. Maybe using `" "` can be a good idea to consider the input `*` as you want it[string].